# Is a good idea create validators that checks if logged in user.id is the same of my row user_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, authlogic

I'm just unsure about the approach. Actually I've this situation:

```
User belongs_to Organization
Organization has_many User

Organization has_many MembershipCard
MembershipCard belongs_to Organization
```

Now, the User is allowed to create a new MembershipCard only if he sets Organization = User.organization (notice that users with higher privileges do not have this limitation).

Currently I handle everything on the controller, however I were thinking about making a validator that ensures `Organization == current_user.Organization (UserSession.find.user)`

Is it a good idea? It looks good for me but I'm really afraid of hardly breaking MVC pattern without a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect time/place/example for you to think on [Authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) as well not just [Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) (authlogic).
With the gem [declarative_authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) its a child's play to do this. You could just simply specify rules in the [authorization rules](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization#authorization-rules):

```
authorization do
  role :user do
    has_permission_on :membership_cards, :to => :create do
      if_attribute :organization => is {user.organization}
    end
  end
end
```

See [Railscast - #188](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization) about using these gems together.

**====== After update on question information: ======**

> "CanCan was inspired by declarative_authorization and aegis" - [from github-cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan#special-thanks)

I looked it up how would you define such a rule with CanCan and there is a snippet on the page [defining abilities for CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)

```
class Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :create, MembershipCard do |card|
      card.organization.user == user
    end
  end
end
```

You still need to customize it for your enviorement, but it should guide you to the solution.

See [Railscast - 192](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) about using CanCan.

Comment: I'm already using cancan for authorization, but I don't know if supports something similar to if_attribute. Where do you put your code? Is it placed in a specific file used by declarative_authorization?

Comment: Woah, you did the job for me, really **thanks** that was more than I expected. And completely answer my question obviously.

Comment: Np man, i'm glad i could help. If you got some game projects going on, love to check 'em out, you could detail your profile a bit [:

Comment: Thanks, I'm working with some people on a small project built with Unity3D but we are still in brainstorming phase. When I'll have something to show you I'll do it for sure ;)